# Buffer in OpenGL to store all shapes?

Tags: cocoa, opengl, buffer

In OpenGL, I have a static camera and a scene that only needs to move when the user "moves the camera".
I have a pretty complex scene in OpenGL, which I regenerate fully at each frame.
Sorry if this is a basic question, but can't I store the scene in a sort of buffer that I then just can tell OpenGL to draw ?

Comment: Do you want to store the image of the scene in a texture, so you only have to draw the texture (genpfault's answer). Or do you want to store the to be rendered scene data in an abstract way (Jerry's answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In "traditional" OpenGL, you'd use a [display list](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/displaylist.htm). In more "modern" OpenGL, you'd use a [vertex buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object).

Comment: Thanks, took a bit of understanding, but am getting there now !

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL doesn't store scenes. It's an drawing API, i.e. what you do is sending drawing commands. Display Lists are just a convenient way to batch up a (large) number of drawing commands. So you also don't "recreate" a scene by redrawing, but you're actually draw the stuff, everytime you issue OpenGL drawing commands. This is important to understand! It implies, that changing something is a scene is not costly on the part of OpenGL since you're redrawing all the things anyway. So there's little benefit designing your program around the (wrong) assumption that OpenGL did some scene management for your.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [FBOs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_EXT_framebuffer_object) for a fast solution.

Alternatively, just don't clear the color buffer each frame.